# Creating a plot with x-axis not to scale in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

My x axis are `x =[0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1]` When I create a graph it looks like this [image]

I want to make a graph that ignores the scale in x-axis and puts the points equidistance from one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot with [`semilogx`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html) function to set log scale of x axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x =np.array([0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1.])
plt.semilogx(x, np.sin(x*x))
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

In common case to put the points equidistance from one another you have to reorganize your data because you may change labels of axis ticks but not points value.

[image]